# Pulsar-Client is not satisfy the required version

Tags: python, pip, chromadb

I ran `pip install pulsar-client` and got:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pulsar-client (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pulsar-client
```

I tried `pip install pulsar-client==3.1.0` and got:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pulsar-client==3.1.0 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pulsar-client==3.1.0
```

How can I fix this?

I am using Python version 3.12.1.

Comment: is this the complete error message? Also what version of python are you using?

Comment: yes it is complete error and my python version is 3.12.1

Comment: Please include this in your question.

Answer (score 2):

The latest version of [pulsar-client](https://pypi.org/project/pulsar-client/#files) was Released on August 30, 2023. The likely cause of your issue is that this package doesn't currently support your python version (3.12.1). To fix this, you may want to downgrade your python version.
You can either use [virtual environments](https://docs.python.org/3.10/tutorial/venv.html#creating-virtual-environments) as this helps you to set up project-specific Python versions (as well as libraries) or you may want to uninstall the unsupported Python version and re-install a lower version. Afterwards, you can go ahead and `pip install pulsar-client` or `python -m pip install pulsar-client`